# Setting visual Studio Debug exe name in the csproj file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, configuration, platform

My objective is to have specific assembly per configuration. For now i am working on the debug configuration.

I have changed my Debug Configuration node in csproj xml file to the following.

```
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'CE_1' ">proj.CE_1</AssemblyName>
<StartAction Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'CE_1' ">proj.CE_1</StartAction>
<DeployDirSuffix>Proj</DeployDirSuffix>
```

In my Project > Properties > Debug the start Action is set to Start Project.

Why is VS08 still looking for Proj/CE.exe (the Assembly name of the project is CE) when i debug this project - when i clearly set it to proj.CE_1 as shown above.

The weird thing is if i just build the project or when Deploying finishes to a device, the exe in the debug folder or on the device is proj.CE_1.exe. The next step after deploying is running the exe and that is the part that is using the old assembly name..aka - The right assembly is being deployed but VS is trying to execute the old assembly name.

Also I am not sure what the StartAction value should be if thats the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You made it conditional for MSBuild but it is not conditional to the debugger.  Which doesn't run MSBuild to find out what to debug, that would be impractical.  

Do favor the built-in way to separate the output of different configurations.  Using different directories instead of different target names.

Comment: i want to debug one of the configurations how is that possible then??? @HansPassant